# Swift - insert into array of characters, functional solution

Tags: arrays, generics, swift, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a function that will take as its argument an array of characters (call it a word) and a single character, and return an array of "words" with the character inserted at all positions:

**Example**

```
typealias Word = [Character]

func insert(letter: Character, into word: Word) -> [Word] {
}
```

So calling:

```
insert("c", into: ["a", "b"])
```

will return:

```
[["c", "a", "b"], ["a", "c", "b"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

The simplest I've come up with so far is:

```
func insert(letter: Character, into word: Word) -> [Word] {

    return Array<Int>(0...word.count).map() {
        var newWord = word
        newWord.insert(letter, atIndex: $0)
        return newWord
    }
}
```

from which I got the generic version:

```
extension Array
{
    func insert(element: T) -> [[T]] {

        return (0...self.count).map() {
            var newArray = self
            newArray.insert(element, atIndex: $0)
            return newArray
        }
    }
}
```

However, this involves making a mutable copy of the input word. It there a better / more elegant / simpler (functional) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would move the "non-mutating array insert" to a separate method:

```
extension Array
{
    func arrayByInserting(element: T, atIndex: Int) -> [T] {
        var result = self
        result.insert(element, atIndex: atIndex)
        return result
    }

    func insert(element: T) -> [[T]] {
        return (0 ... self.count).map() { self.arrayByInserting(element, atIndex: $0) }
    }
}
```

Then your question (as I understand it) if there is a better way for the
the `arrayByInserting` method. Actually your method looks fine to me. You need
to return a new array, so you can just as well start with a copy of self.

It could be written slightly *shorter* using slices:

```
func arrayByInserting(element: T, atIndex: Int) -> [T] {
    return self[0 ..< atIndex] + [element] + self[atIndex ..< self.count]
}
```

However, a quick test showed that this method is about 10 times *slower* than your method.

Answer (score 1):

You can find very interesting functional examples in Swift here:
[objc.io Functional Snippets](http://www.objc.io/snippets/)

The "permutations" snippets is what you're looking for.

Here a simplified example for you. But I strongly recommend the objc.io snippets.

The Array Extension:

```
extension Array {
   var decompose : (head: T, tail: [T])? {
      return (count > 0) ? (self[0], Array(self[1..<count])) : nil
   }
}
```

And here the generic function:

```
func between<T>(x: T, ys: [T]) -> [[T]] {
 if let (head, tail) = ys.decompose {
    return [[x] + ys] + between(x, tail).map { [head] + $0 }
 } else {
    return [[x]]
 }
}
```

This should solve your problem:

```
let char: Character = "c"
let charArray = ["a", "b"] as [Character]
let r = between(char, charArray)
```

Comment: Nice solution (but terribly slow: about factor 1000 slower than the method in the question - just stating).

Comment: Yep ... sadly :-/
But the question seems to call for a _functional_ approach.
How much Swift compiler and optimiser are ready for Functional Programming, remains an open question to me. And, probably, a bit off topic.